# Cassandra Bulk Load SSTable JMX OOM error

Tags: java, eclipse, cassandra

I'm a student doing a project on Big Data using Cassandra. I have to bulk load quite a bit of data for my project.

My rows are quite large at 470 cols.

I'm trying to utilize a SSTable + JMX loader strategy. Whenever I try to load the SSTables to my localhost pc I get an OOM error. I'm not sure what to do and I've worked so hard -- its 4:15 am right now -- I've googled the problem but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm launching my program in Eclipse, so that might make a difference.

Thanks in advance.

more details:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

caused somewhere in the jmx bulk loader:

> at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.EstimatedHistogram$EstimatedHistogramSerializer.deserialize(EstimatedHistogram.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableMetadata$SSTableMetadataSerializer.deserialize(SSTableMetadata.java:463)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableMetadata$SSTableMetadataSerializer.deserialize(SSTableMetadata.java:448)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableMetadata$SSTableMetadataSerializer.deserialize(SSTableMetadata.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.openMetadata(SSTableReader.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.openForBatch(SSTableReader.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader$1.accept(SSTableLoader.java:112)
>     at java.io.File.list(File.java:1161)    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.openSSTables(SSTableLoader.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bulkLoad(StorageService.java:3698)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)   at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
>     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
>     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)

Comment: Can you post the details of the error?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it works now. I'll try to repost what so as to avoid this problem
[image]

1) I was using an old version of cassandra 2.0.5 iirc, so i upgraded to newest one.

2) double checked the cassandra.yaml file.